# can a send parallel sync request from browser window and async request from webworker?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-worker

First I will start requests to a server in webworker:

```
function test (){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "/api/just_sleep?time=3", true);
    xhr.send(null);
    setTimeout(test, 10000);
}
test()
```

And the server every 10 seconds are correctly requests.
But when I'm in the "main thread" browser execute this query:

```
$.ajax('/api/just_sleep?time=60', {"async": false});
```

Requests from the worker stop's unti that server response to a request in the main window.

Is it possible to somehow get around this behavior?

Comment: Why do you use async=false? Obviously it blocks browser for 60 seconds.

Comment: Yes, i know it. I did this on purpose in order to verify this behavior. The question "Is it necessary to synchronous requests" is not discussed.